# Prepositions/adpositions with genitive?

Tags: preposition, genitive

In Latin, there are prepositions that may be followed by a noun in accusative (like *ad*), ablative (*cum*) or both (*in*).

I once thought *ope* was a preposition to be used with genitive, which I found pretty interesting because most Latin grammars do not mention it (I think I once read one that did, but I can't find it now). Then I realized it is just the dative of *ops* (in my defense, ope -*by the power or support* of sth- has a very preposition-ish meaning). Nevertheless, doing some linguistics-fiction I wondered it was a feasible way for such a preposition to *evolve* after the desappearence of other uses of *ops*.

And then I found [this site](http://www.informalmusic.com/latinsoc/prep.html), stating that there is the preposition *tenus*, which actually *works* with genitive. I've never heard of that one, and the page does not cite any sources, but there are [other sources](http://latin.campus.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=tenus&ending=) that favor the point.

My Latin is mostly *ecclesiastical*, so I am more or less ignorant of many classical- and medieval-specific features.

My question is: were prepositions/adpositions with genitive a real thing at any point in Latin history? Is there more than one such adposition?

**Update:** some people have pointed that *tenus* is indeed a *postposition*, since it goes *after* the noun being modified. In the meantime, I have learnt that in linguistics there is a more general word, *adposition* to embrace both pre- and postpositions. I was unaware of any of these two words: good to learn new things. Thanks @Cerberus.

I added the concept to the question's title. I left the word *preposition* here and there for a number of reasons: 1) both sources cited treat *tenus* as a *preposition* (even clarifying it has to be used after the noun), 2) there is no `adposition` tag in Latin.SE, 3) in English, prepositions *may* be used *after* nouns in certain circumstances (see [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/preposition?s=t), under the title *Usage Note*), and some definitions [confirm it](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apreposition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b).

Comment: It seems that you could make the argument that "causa," "gratia," and "ergo" when preceded by the genitive act as prepostions.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure there are any pure prepositions that take the genitive other than *tenus*...

Comment: @nick do you know during which period(s) was *tenus* used and how frequent was its use?

Comment: Wait, now I'm dying to know what linguistics fiction is.

Comment: But...can *tenus* be used as a preposition? I've only ever seen it used as a postposition.

Comment: @Cerberus, which makes it even weirder. Anyway, I was asking for in a broad sense of _preposition_ by the function of modifying the grammatical function (hence it doesn't matter to me whether the word goes before or after the noun/adjective/pronoun being modified)

Comment: @Rafael: Okay, and does a noun in the ablative that has a genitive with it have the appropriate function, like *ope* + gen.? Both have 1 dependent noun, and both can function externally as an adverbial phrase. At any rate, then you should probably change *preposition* into some other term. And *causa* and *gratia* would probably qualify.

Comment: @JoelDerfner, hahaha, it is just a wordplay with science-fiction, where linguistics is the science. I mean to conjecture what in some hypothetical parallel universe could have happened.

Comment: @Cerberus, interesting. I rather look for an authoritative ruling, like a grammar textbook or an academic paper saying they are/aren't prepositions -postpositions [included](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apreposition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)-. I haven't heard the case of _tenus_ before, and I don't think _gratia_ or _causa_ qualify, because they are obviously nouns.

Comment: Or, if most people agree, I can change the word _preposition_ for the more proper _adposition_, of which I wasn't aware up to 1 min ago O:)

Comment: Considering what you're after, I think adposition would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find several examples thanks to Cassell's "Latin Dictionary," and Allen and Greenough's "New Latin Grammar."  First, `tenus` is mentioned as taking either the genitive or ablative.  It references Vergil, Livy, and Lucretius as having examples of the genitive use.

From the grammar book, it mentions that `pridie`, `postridie`, and `ergo` can take the genitive.  Some examples:

```
eius legis ergo - on account of this law
pridie (postridie) eius diei - the day before (after) that
```

So there you have at least two examples of a preposition taking the genitive and placed in front of the word.  The grammar book points out that the second example there is from prose of the Republican Period, and not found elsewhere at that time.

Comment: I am tempted to read *pridie* and *postridie* as temporal ablatives of a noun that is rarely used in other cases. In this reading genitive is natural: *pridie eius diei* is "on the preceding day of that day". The line between a declined noun requiring a genitive attribute and a preposition requiring genitive is thin.

Comment: @coralv Lewis and Short list _pridie_, _postridie_ and _ergo_ as _adverbs_ (the first two derived in fact from abl. _die_). Can you confirm there is a dictionary listing them as prepositions or other type of adpositions?

Comment: That's a good point, the grammar book doesn't say that they're prepositions, it just gives them in reference to using the genitive.  `Tenus` and `ergo` are listed in my dictionary as prepositions but, indeed, `pridei` and `postridie` are adverbs.

Comment: @Rafael Prepositions are just adverbs that lost independent adverbial usage.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add references to where this is found in these grammars? I am desperately searching for adpositions that take the genitive.

Comment: @CannedMan see section 359b.