# Regarding the mode of "terram" in Deuteronomy 28:38

Tags: vulgata, ablative, accusative, case

[Deuteronomy 28:38](http://sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/deu028.htm#038) reads:

> Sementem multam jacies in terram, et modicum congregabis: quia locustæ devorabunt omnia.

I think the first phrase before the comma has the following structure (but reordered; e.g. accusatives come before the verb, and subject is implicit in the verb):

> [subject/nominative] [verb] [object/accusative] preposition [ablative]

However, *terram* is in [accusative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terram), instead of in [ablative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terra#Latin) (*terrā*). The object of the phrase is clearly *sementis* (hence the accusative mode *sementem*), whereas *in* is indicating an ablative of place. Why is then *terram* in accusative?

---

Quaestio brevis. Quid "terram" est accusativum in [Deuteronomium 28:38](http://sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/deu028.htm#038)? Non debet sit ablativum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all prepositions are created equal.

Some prepositions need to be followed by ablative as you say. Examples are *cum* (e.g. cum Ipso), *sine* (sine Deo nihil), *de* (de hoc mundo).

Yet most prepositions need to be followed by accusative, like *ante* (ante constitutionem mundi), *per* (per Ipsum), *post* (post mortem).

**A number of prepositions may be followed by both acc. and abl.**, with different meanings, as *in*, *sub*, *super*. **The rule of thumb with these three is that accusative adds movement** to the meaning of the preposition:

- **in+[abl]** → *in*, *on*, *at*;
- **in+[acc]** → *to*, *into*, *towards*.

In the quote from Deuteronomy, the seed is to be [thrown](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Diacio) *to the ground*.

See also: i) L&S entry for [in](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Din1), and ii) [this list](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Din1) (and also [this one](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/portable:latin-prepositions)) of prepositions and the cases they are followed by (none of both is exhaustive, and the exact content of a complete list is disputed).

In the lists you can see that some are said to be followed by [genitive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/883/prepositions-adpositions-with-genitive), like **ope**, and **tenus**. These are listed by some as prepositions, but not universally agreed as such. My perception in this issue is they are nouns in the process of mutating from/to prepositions by gaining/losing cases (either created by generalization or falling out of use). Note that ope is said by L&S to be the ablative of [ops](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dops1), which itself is not attested, being another example of a [defective paradigm](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/vicis-no-singular-nominative). Other cases of *ops* are also rare.

Comment: Oh no, more exceptions to learn! Thanks. I just realised the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_case) on the ablative makes similar comments about the use of prepositions, distinguishing the case of _in_.

Comment: @luchonacho hahaha, _ánimo_. Back in the day it helped me a lot to learn a handful of texts that were already familiar to me in Spanish by memory, and make sense of them afterwards. E.g. _Pater Noster qui es in caelis... et ne nos inducas in tentationem..._

Comment: That's a great example of both uses of _in_. _¡Gracias!_