# How do postpositions fit into Latin syntax?

Tags: syntax, preposition

In a comment on [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8880/406), luchonacho comments that *tenus* is a preposition taking the genitive; this seemed odd to me, since I'd never considered *tenus* anything akin to a preposition.

*Tenus* seems to be a "postposition", in that it comes after a noun. But how does this work, syntactically? Are "postpositions" a proper category in Latin, like prepositions are? If not, what are they?

Comment: *Causā, gratiā* are other common examples.

Comment: You will have to rewrite other parts of the textbooks too. *Cum amicis eius* 'With his/her friends' *Ablativus Collativus.*

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/883/prepositions-adpositions-with-genitive

Comment: Plus, especially in the poets, words that are usually prepositions are sometimes used as postpositions – e.g., *super* in Lucretius, *DRN* 6.186: scilicet hoc densis fit nubibus et simul alte / extructis aliis **alias super** impete miro. I'm sure I've also seen this done occasionally in prose too.

Answer (score 2):

Can we broaden the discussion to cover these five postpositional prepositions, please.

**[scuolaeculturaoggi](https://scuolaeculturaoggi.myblog.it/media/00/01/1123728835.doc)** lists "PREPOSIZIONI CHE REGGONO IL  GENITIVO  (generalmente premesso):

> ***causa***  = *per*
>   ***gratia***    = *per*
>   ***tenus*** = *fino a
>   ***instar*** = a mo' di, a somiglianza di, come un
>   **N.B.**  *tenus*  si può costruire indifferentemente e con lo stesso significato anche con l’ablativo

**[Paulo Barbosa](http://topicosdelatinidade.blogspot.com/2011/05/preposicoes-e-ablativos-preposicionais.html)**, gives these five with Genitive (4 sempre **posposições**)

> *Emolumendi sui **gratia*** = por amor do seu interesse.
>   *Usurpandi juris **causa*** = por motivos de exercer jurisdição.
>   *Voluminis **instar*** = à maneira de volume
>   *Forminidis **ergo*** = por causa do medo. (porém Tito Lívio a emprega como preposição.)
>   ***Clam*** patris = às escondida do pai.